# Hide Notification badge counter

Tags: windows, windows-11, operating-systems

Windows 11 Taskbar:

[image: Windows 11 Taskbar]

I want hide 0 badge on taskbar. My Windows 11 version: 22H2 22621.2134

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I do not think you can. This came, went, and came on Windows Insider and  Microsoft has landed on displaying it. Overall it is easier this way. I am using build ...  .2361 a bit newer.

Comment: @John - You absolutely can.  “Show badges (unread messages counter) on taskbar apps” controls the behavior of even the registry key TaskbarBadges

Comment: I tried that here and it does not work. Windows 11 remains a work in progress. It is not the only setting that has gone bad with the newest build.